# How to delete a set of Entities using Objectify .ids()

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

I'm reading a set of Entities from GAE using Objectify:

```
List<CountStore> myList = ofy().load().type(CountStore.class).list();
```

I then filter, and remove some of the elements of myList. I now want to delete all the ids in the remaining list. I think the right approach is to use .ids():

```
ofy().delete().type(CountStore.class).ids(myList);
```

But this doesn't work - it crashes (see below), as it is expecting myList to be a Long or a String. Can anyone advise the best way to delete a set of Entities?

Thanks!

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: id 'com.xyz.abc.CountStore@53d71fff' must be String or Long
at com.googlecode.objectify.util.DatastoreUtils.createKey(DatastoreUtils.java:66)
at com.googlecode.objectify.util.DatastoreUtils.createKeys(DatastoreUtils.java:112)
at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.DeleteTypeImpl.ids(DeleteTypeImpl.java:91)
at com.xyz.abc.CounterServlet.doGet(CountrServlet.java:45)
```

...

Comment: In what way does it not work?  Your example is an asynchronous delete - you can add `now()` for a synchronous operation.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to add that the delete crashes - see above for first few lines of crash report.

Comment: Your argument to `ids()` is a list of `Countstore` according to your code sample - it should be a list of your entities' `@Id` properties, which will be strings or longs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for pointing out that an array of Long IDs is all that is needed. The answer really was quite simply to create an ArrayList of IDs as I filtered the ones Entities I want to delete:

```
  ArrayList<Long> idList = new ArrayList<Long>();

  //Do the Filtering and add IDs to the idList array the delete them all
  ofy().delete().type(CountStore.class).ids(idList).now();
```

Comment: You can also just `ofy().delete().entities(...yourlistofentities...).now()`

Answer (score 0):

I had abstracted out the delete as follows:

```
    public void deleteEntities(List<BaseClass> entities){
        try{
            ofy().delete().entities(entities);
        }catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error("Exception", ex);
        }
    }
```

Then dumped the derived class objects:

```
    List<DerivedClass> params = receivedFromSomeOtherFunction();
    List<BaseCLass> params2 = new ArrayList<BaseClass>();
    params2.addAll(params);
```

And then call deleteEntities as follows:

```
    deleteEntities(params2);
```

However, one drawback I found that sometimes this function call takes time to delete all the elements although the function call returns immediately probably because it deletes the objects asynchronously.